# OWIN Cookies not being removed by IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, owin

I'm experiencing a problem where the following code does not appear to be working as expected:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

When this is executed the above line of code I would expect the following property to be false

```
AuthenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

But it is not, it remains true (FOR IE ONLY, I'm using IE 11)

I'm exposing my Owin context through the following property:

```
public IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication; 
    } 
}
```

I am also attempting to manually remove the authentication cookie using the following code:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var appCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[".AspNet.AuthCookie"];

if (appCookie != null)
{
    appCookie = new HttpCookie(".AspNet.AuthCookie");
    appCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(appCookie);                
}
```

Which, again, does not work in IE. It works in Chrome.

FYI, i am manually setting the name of the cookie in my Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Config.AuthenticationCookieTimeOutMinutes),
    CookieHttpOnly = true, 
    CookieName = ".AspNet.AuthCookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest                
});
```

There is plenty online about the Signout() method not working properly, but most solutions are to remove the cookie manually, which i am having no joy with. Why would this not work in IE 11?

**UPDATE**

So I was unable to fix the issue with cookies in IE, however was able to overcome this issue by overriding the HandleUnauthorizedRequest virtual of the AuthorizeAttribute to see if the user has been authenticated, then double checks the CurrentUser held in session

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    UserAccount currentUser = (UserAccount)filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionStrings.CurrentUser];

    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated && currentUser != null)
    { 
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Updated provided in question. Had to override HandleUnauthorizedRequest of AuthorizeAttribute in the end, a bit of a hack, but only way i could find around it